# Explain "magnetic" deflection of a charge moving radially relative to a conducting wire in terms of relativistic effects

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Apparently some people are unfamiliar with the concepts addressed in my question.  I have found several videos on the topic.  All of which follow the development I referenced in the Feynman Lectures.

Here is one of the better videos https://youtu.be/j2AQAVIzx70

My derivation below is more general, but still uses the case of a test charge moving parallel to the wire.

Explaining the deflection of a charge moving parallel to the length of a conducting wire is fairly easy.  For example The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II, Chapter 13-6 [The relativity of magnetic and electric fields](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html#Ch13-S6).  The Lorentz force law states that a particle of the same charge moving radially with the same speed through the same point in the wire's rest frame will experience a force normal to its velocity, equal in magnitude to that experienced by the charge moving parallel to the wire.

Is there an equally simple and compelling account of the force deflecting a radially moving charge as there is for a parallel moving charge?

---

This is my derivation of the component form of the Lorentz force law for the case of a charge moving parallel to the current.

- Linear charge density in the rest frame of the conduction cloud
  and wire, respectively: $\lambda_{c},\lambda_{w}.$
- Linear charge densities in the conduction cloud rest frame: $\bar{\lambda_{c}},\bar{\lambda_{w}}.$
- Linear charge densities in the test charge rest frame: $\bar{\bar{\lambda_{c}}},\bar{\bar{\lambda_{w}}},\bar{\bar{\lambda}}.$
- Rapidity of the conduction cloud and test particle relative to the
  wire rest frame:$\theta_{c},\theta_{q}.$
- Rapidity of the test particle relative to the conduction cloud frame:$\theta_{cq}=\theta_{q}-\theta_{c}.$
- Lorentz transformation components: $\gamma_{i}=\cosh\theta_{i},\sigma_{i}=\sinh\theta_{i}.$
- Corresponding signed speed: $v_{i}=\mathrm{c}\beta_{i}=\mathrm{c}\sigma_{i}/\gamma_{i}.$
- Current in the wire: $I=\lambda_{c}v_{c}.$
- Transverse momentum increment $\Delta p.$

Since the wire is neutrally charged in its rest frame, the proper
density $\bar{\lambda_{c}}$ of the conduction cloud is related to
that of the wire by the Lorentz factor $\gamma_{c},$ giving

$$
0=\lambda_{c}+\lambda_{w}=\gamma_{c}\bar{\lambda_{c}}+\lambda_{w}.
$$

We use this equation along with elementary hyperbolic trigonometry
to express the net linear charge density in the test charge frame
in terms of speed of the charge and the current in the wire

$$\begin{aligned}
\bar{\bar{\lambda}}=&\bar{\bar{\lambda_{c}}}+\bar{\bar{\lambda_{w}}}\\
=&\gamma_{cq}\bar{\lambda_{c}}+\gamma_{q}\lambda_{w}\\
=&\left(\gamma_{q}\gamma_{c}-\sigma_{q}\sigma_{c}\right)\bar{\lambda_{c}}-\gamma_{q}\gamma_{c}\bar{\lambda_{c}}\\
=&-\beta_{q}\beta_{c}\gamma_{q}\gamma_{c}\bar{\lambda_{c}}\\
=&-\frac{v_{q}v_{c}}{\mathrm{c}_{2}}\gamma_{q}\lambda_{c}\\
=&-\gamma_{q}v_{q}\frac{I}{\mathrm{c}_{2}}.\\
\end{aligned}$$

Since the transverse momentum is Lorentz invariant we have

$$
\Delta p=\bar{\bar{f}}\bar{\bar{\Delta t}}=q\bar{\bar{E}}\bar{\bar{\Delta t}}=f\Delta t=f\gamma_{q}\bar{\bar{\Delta t}}.
$$

Using the well-known formula for the electric field of a line charge
we obtain the component form of the Lorenz force law

$$
\frac{\bar{\bar{E}}}{\gamma_{q}}=\frac{f}{q}=\frac{\bar{\bar{\lambda}}}{\gamma_{q}2\pi\epsilon_{o}r}=-Bv_{q}.
$$

---

A positively charged test particle moving in the direction of the current is attracted to the wire because the cloud density increases more than the wire density due to the nature of the Lorentz factor $\gamma$.  Using the Lorentz force law we know the same positive charge moving radially toward the wire will deflect in the direction opposite the current.  Thus the wire appears to be a dipole from the perspective of the test charge

Qualitatively, I can say this is again due to the nature of the Lorentz factor.  A segment of the conduction cloud moving toward the path of the test charge will have a greater relative speed than an equivalent segment moving away from the path.

When I get a chance, I will try to give the quantitative argument.

Comment: I am baffled by the down-vote and the vote to close this question.  Please explain why this was done

Answer (score -1):

Let's say we have two positively and negatively charged spinning disks close to each other. Like a plate capacitor with round spinning plates.

Now we use energy to pull the plates apart. Classical physics says the radial motion of charges causes a Lorentz-force that cause the capacitor to slow down.

Relativity says that the rotational inertia of the capacitor increases, which causes it to slow down.

Correction. One of the disks is not spinning. Now we have a magnetic field of the spinning disk and a charged object moving away from it. Just like an electric  charge moving away from an electric wire.

As requested, let's consider similar but little bit different scenario:

Electrons move in a wire. Positive test charges are staying still around the wire.

Now when we move those test charges away, we can note that the current in the wire decreases, electrons move slower.

The explanation for this  is that the mass-energy of the fuel that was used went into the electrons. And the electrons did work on said mass-energy, forcing said mass-energy to move at the drift speed of the electrons. This caused the slowdown. We could call this a collision.

Now let us go to the rest frame of the electrons. In this frame the test charges are moving, so their electric fields are squeezed. When the squeezed fields start to move away, the fields Wigner-rotate. So now the test charges pull sideways on the electrons, and electron pull sideways on the test charges. And that pull is the Lorentz-force.

That Wigner-rotation is the effect where the left and right side of the field of a test charge start simultaneously to move away from the wire in the test charge's frame, but non-simultaneously in the electron's frame.

Comment: I'm asking about changing this development by changing the direction of test charge velocity to be normal ti the current https://youtu.be/j2AQAVIzx70

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton OK,will do. :)

Comment: I did down-vote your answer, not because it is a bad answer to a good question.  It's just a bad answer to my good question.  I'm assuming you've read the second volume of the Feynman Lectures on Physics.  What you are talking about is scattered throughout those pages.  I am completely  baffled by the votes to close my question.  Do you agree that, to a radially moving test charge one half of the wire will appear positively charged, and the other (equally) negatively charged?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Radially moving test charge feels such a field that could be produced, either by a non-neutral charge  distribution, or fields being squeezed and tilted. A radially moving test observer observes that field are squeezed and tilted. Or do you know a reason why said observer would observe wires being charged, I mean without using a test charge, but using relativity and some knowledge of the positions of the charges?

Comment: It's a matter of interpretation.  In the case of the test charge moving parallel to the current, it is easy to show that the "magnetic" effect is to be purely electrical in the test charge rest frame.  In that case the whole wire presents a uniform charge to the test particle.   I'm suggesting that something similar is happening in the case of the radially moving test charge.  The "rotated field lines" argument leads to the appearance that the wire is asymmetrically charged.   Purcell sets up the problem in terms of transformed field lines and leaves it as an exercise. I haven't worked it yet.